# Stringify An Object Key's Name

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I've tried `JSON.stringify()` and `Object.Keys()` however they're not working for me, they do not output the Object Key's Name

My .JSON File:

```
{
  "KittenLauncher": {
    "a": "value1",
    "b": "value2"
  }
}
```

My Current JS File:

```js
const obj = require('../../someJSONFileIHave.json');
let rname = "Kitten";
let rating;

function getValueByPartialKey(obj, key) {

    try {
        rating = 'A, B, C';
        return (Object.entries(obj).find(([k, v]) => k.includes(key)))[1]; // Returns KittenLauncher as an [Object]
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Object Key does not exist!")
    }

}

return console.log(JSON.stringify(getValueByPartialKey(obj, rName))); // Outputs "{"a": "value1","b": "value2"}"
```

I'd like it to output the Object Key's name as such: "KittenLauncher"

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: You're trying to get the name of the variable? Why?

Comment: `Object.keys({KittenLauncher})[0]` will return a string `KittenLauncher`, but I fail to see the point in trying to do this.

Comment: you want object name (KittenLauncher)? instead of object keys name (a and b)?

Comment: Your variable `KittenLauncher` contains a pointer to your object.  Your object does not have any idea what variables might be pointing at it.  There could be hundreds or one.  This request (without any context) doesn't really make any sense.  Maybe you should back up and describe what problem you're actually trying to solve because whatever it is, this is not the way you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your .js file, you already have,

```
const obj = require('../../someJSONFileIHave.json');
```

And your JSON file is,

```
{
  "KittenLauncher": {
    "a": "value1",
    "b": "value2"
  }
}
```

So, to get KittenLauncher as output, you can use,

```
const output = Object.keys(obj)[0]  `//Output is KittenLauncher`
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I require (Object.entries(robj).find(([k, v]) => k.includes(key))); inside >w<